# How can I access identity profiles and certificates with iPhone SDK?

Tags: iphone, certificate, security-framework

I am trying to verify the user identity on my application using a certificate / identity that the user has stored by opening a .cer / .p12 attached to an email. The certificate appears on the settings app of the phone under the group "Configuration Profiles".

Is there any way of accessing the certificate using the iphone SDK (I have tried to use the Security Framework, but it seems that it is only possible to access certificates stored in the application keychain or other keychains from its group)?

Comment: Juanjo, Have you found a solution to your question?

Comment: No, I am going to try to talk directly to Apple (my client is a government institution here in Spain, so maybe they will have some interest in using the iPhone platform in that sector), maybe they can made some API available.

Answer (score 1):

You talked about the Security framework already, but did you [try the following functions in the doc](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Security/Reference/certifkeytrustservices/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30000157)?

I personally never tried/had to do this myself, but anyway it seems that there are some functions like `SecCertificateCreateWithData` in the framework, so you should be able to build a `SecCertificateRef` from some NSData/CFDataRef… data which is the content of your mail attachment.

From there you may use it as any other certificate using the other functions (like you would do for a certificate extracted from the Keychain)

Well this is only a guess after simply reading the documentation but let's give it a try as the doc seems to indicate it is the way to go.